# Jarray. I need to retrieve a Jarray with unique elements

Tags: c#, json

I have a JArray from a json-file like this:

```
[
  {
    "pos": 36,
    "name": "name1",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "pos": 36,
    "name": "name2",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "pos": 36,
    "name": "name2",
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

And I need save json back with unique elements filtered by set of fields. The set of fields can be any.

**Update** In real file I have 3000 elements in the JArray and about 20 fields. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

**Example 1** If I filter the JArray by name I expect to get

```
[
   {
     "pos": 36,
     "name": "name1",
     "id": 1
   },
   {
     "pos": 36,
     "name": "name2",
     "id": 2
   }
]
```

**Example 2** If I filter the JArray by "name" and "pos" I expect to get

```
[
   {
     "pos": 36,
     "name": "name1",
     "id": 1
   }
]
```

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried, desired output and what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: 1: create a class to match each of these object in the Jarray 2: deserialize each object inside the Jarray into a list of class object 3: filter them by the property you wanted 4: serialize them back to json 5: save

Comment: Why {
     "pos": 36,
     "name": "name1",
     "id": 1
   },
   {
     "pos": 36,
     "name": "name2",
     "id": 2
   }, not {
     "pos": 36,
     "name": "name1",
     "id": 1
   },
   {
     "pos": 36,
     "name": "name2",
     "id": 3
   }  What is the difference? We can not help you if you don't know what are you really doing

Comment: It sounds like you want to find distinct elements using some subset of property values, but if so, why would finding distinct elements *by "name" and "pos"* return fewer elements than just by "name"?  All array items have an identical `"pos"` value of `36` so finding distinct elements by  "name" and "pos" should have the same effect as finding distinct elements by "name" only.  Did you mean to write, **Example 2 If I filter the JArray by "pos" I expect to get**?

Comment: As noted above we are having trouble understanding your requirements.  That being said, if example 2 should have been **Example 2 If I filter the JArray by "pos" I expect to get**, is this what you want: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GCH3we.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with this code without serializing(with Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;)

first find unique element and then Serialize to json(Newtonsoft.Json)

If you want to group several, I realized something from your example, you can write this code

```
var newLists = List.GroupBy(x => new { b = x["name"] }).Select(x => x.First())
 .GroupBy(x => new { b = x["pos"] }) .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
//convert to string json 
var str1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newLists);
```

Result

```
[{
"pos":36,
"name":"name1",
"id":1
}]
```

If you want to group only once(Really distinct ), use this code

```
var newList = List.GroupBy(x => new { b = x["name"], a = x["pos"] })
.Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
//convert to string json 
var str1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newList);
```

Result:

```
[{
"pos":36,
"name":"name1",
"id":1
},
{
"pos":36,
"name":"name2",
"id":2
}]
```

Base Code:

```
JArray List = new JArray();
List = JArray.Parse(@"[
  {
    ""pos"": 36,
    ""name"": ""name1"",
    ""id"": 1
  },
  {
    ""pos"": 36,
    ""name"": ""name2"",
    ""id"": 2
  },
  {
    ""pos"": 36,
    ""name"": ""name2"",
    ""id"": 3
  }
]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PropertyModel
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public bool IsToProcess { get; set; }
}

List<PropertyModel> SummaryStructure = new List<PropertyModel>();

JArray SummaryIn = JArray.Parse(jsonString);    

var model = SummaryIn[0];

var props = model.Cast<JProperty>();

foreach (var p in props)
{
    var property = new PropertyModel(){ ShortName = p.Name};

    SummaryStructure.Add(property);
}

var SummaryOut = SummaryIn.ToList();

foreach (PropertyModel item in SummaryStructure)
{
    if (item.IsToProcess)
    {
        SummaryOut = SummaryOut.GroupBy(p => p[item.ShortName])
                               .Select(p => p.First())
                               .ToList();
    }
}
```

It was easy :). Maybe someone knows how to pack it in one linq?